# How to quickly change file path from a list of folder names

Tags: linux, bash

I need to run a command in linux and it goes like:

```
blahblahblah subject1/image.png subject1/post_image.png
```

I have a list of the subject folders, and the input name in the folder (image.png) stays the same, and the output is the same too. 
I want to create a whole list that looks like

```
blahblahblah subject1/image.png subject1/post_image.png
blahblahblah subject2/image.png subject2/post_image.png
...
blahblahblah subject200/image.png subject200/post_image.png
```

If I have a list from subject1 to subject200, what is the easiest way to create a txt file of that command for each folder?

Comment: I don't get that part : "create a txt file of that command for each folder". Which is the most important one :-D.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand is you want to store each command in a text file:

```
for i in {1..200}
do
   echo "blahblahblah subject$i/image.png subject$i/post_image.png" > $i.txt
done
```

Comment: I don't see the point of creating such a file, while the OP can run each command in the loop, but that seems right...

Comment: Me neither @n00dl3

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`var=20
s=seq 1 $var
for i in $s
do
    mkdir subject$i
    blahblahblah subject$i/image.png subject$i/post_image.png
done`

Put `` in s=seq 1 $var